# vscode include asset folder to /build

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, visual-studio-code

I have a project, it's not Angular2 or anything. I'm just using typescript in vscode.

I've setup my tsconfig.json to output my .ts files to a single file in ./build. However, for convenience purposes I would also like to include a folder or file i.e: /lib which contains all the js files I'm using such as linq (http://www.javascriptlinq.com/), jquery & bootstrap etc...

Basically, I want the end product of my project concists of 1 or 2 .js files.

Comment: I don't think the TypeScript compiler supports that. Have you tried a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)?

Comment: A  very HACKY alternative to a bundler or build tool would be using the --allowJs compiler flag to compile your libs as well.

Comment: That'll do. Actually, I was wondering why it didn't include any of the files in my /src/lib. It turns out I can't go deeper than /src/**/*. But thanks, that'll work for me. It's a long story why I have to do it like this but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to toskv in the rely, the workaround for me was to add

```
"allowJs": true
```

in tsconfig.json. Also,

```
"include": [ "src/**/*" ]
```

doesn't like it when i add folders deeper than that so i had to chuck them in

```
/src/lib
```

rather than

```
/src/lib/somelib/file.js
```